# Error: Symbol Zeros is already exposed as (), when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

I am getting this error when importing tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SymbolAlreadyExposedError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

File C:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:473
    471 if hasattr(_current_module, "keras"):
    472   try:
--> 473     keras._load()
    474   except ImportError:
    475     pass

File C:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py:41, in LazyLoader._load(self)
     39 """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     40 # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 41 module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     42 self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     44 # Emit a warning if one was specified

.....
.....
.....

File C:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_export.py:351, in api_export.set_attr(self, func, api_names_attr, names)
    349 if api_names_attr in func.__dict__:
    350   if not self._allow_multiple_exports:
--> 351     raise SymbolAlreadyExposedError(
    352         'Symbol %s is already exposed as %s.' %
    353         (func.__name__, getattr(func, api_names_attr)))  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    354 setattr(func, api_names_attr, names)

SymbolAlreadyExposedError: Symbol Zeros is already exposed as ().
```

I am using anaconda3 on Win 10 x64 and I have updated python and tensorflow, however the issue persists.

Python version: 3.10.13
Tensorflow version: 2.10.0
pip version: 23.2.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue is might be conflict between different versions of TensorFlow, or possible corrupted installation.
We need to check that tensorFlow is installed correctly in your environment. if its not installed properly try this below command to install.

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.10.0
```

There is no other TensorFlow Installation interfering with the one you want to use. Sometimes Anaconda environments or different Python installations can have conflicting TensorFlow Versions. By using this below command we can check if there are multiple TensorFlow installations.

```
pip list | grep tensorflow
```

if we have multiple versions, need to uninstall the conflicting ones by using this below command.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow_other_version
```

Follow this steps if still issue persists, need to try creating a new Anaconda environment and reinstalling TensorFlow by using this below command.

```
conda create -n new_env python=3.10 conda activate new_env pip install tensorflow==2.10.0
```